# scala case class copy method is unseen from java code

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a scala case class.
i'm trying to copy it with obj.copy() from java but i don't see any such method

what i did currently was a workaround as:

```
  // Hack, copy was not visible from java code.
  def doCopy(): MyCaseClass = {
    return this.copy()
  }
```

now doCopy() is visible from java.
is there a better way to do it than this hack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method `copy()` in `case class`.

Let's see all methods generated in `case class`:

```
$ echo 'case class T(a1: String, a2: Int)' > test.scala
$ scalac -Xprint:typer test.scala
```

You'll find this method:

```
<synthetic> def copy(a1: String = a1, a2: Int = a2): T = new T(a1, a2);
```

There are no default parameters in `Java`, so you have to specify all parameters. So method `copy` is useless in `Java`.

`case class` should be immutable, so you don't need to `copy` it without changing fields.

Instead of `obj2= obj.copy()` you can use `obj2= obj`.